# Eloquent restore() function on soft deletes failing to restore

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I recently added soft deletes on my user model and the delete part of it works perfectly, however when I try to restore I get an error that says `Call to a member function restore() on a non-object`.

My code for restoring a soft deleted user is as follows:

```
public function putActivateUser()
    {
        $user = Emp::onlyTrashed()->where('id', '=', Input::get('actEmpId'))->first();
        $user->restore();

        return Redirect::route('user_data')
        ->with('message', 'Bruker '.$user->user_name.' aktivert.');
    }
```

The form for the user activation:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/ressurect_user', 'method' => 'PUT')) }} 
        {{ Form::select('actEmpId', $deactEmps) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Aktiver Bruker') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

A dd on $user returns null for some reason, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently user with id from the form is not found with `onlyTrashed` scope.
You should check the query (run DB::getQueryLog() for example) and data in your db, but first change the method to `firstOrFail`:

```
$user = Emp::onlyTrashed()->where('id', '=', Input::get('actEmpId'))->firstOrFail();
```

It will throw `ModelNotFoundException` if nothing was found, so you can catch it and do whatever is needed, thus avoid calling method on null error.

Comment: Hey, it seemed to work when I changed ->first() to ->firstOrFail().
One odd thing though, the first time I ran it it activated everyone in the list and not just one, but it seems to be working now (any idea why?). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: it shouldn't do that, unless you used `get()` instead of first and by chance Input::get('..') were null. Changing `first()` to `firstOrFail()` isn't reason to work or not, so definitely there was something wrong with either data in DB or input.

Comment: Right, retested it now. Works for both first() and firstOrFail(), get() returns the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Emp::withTrashed()->where('id','=',Input::get('actEmpId'))->restore();
```